# How do I link python tkinter widgets created in a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget

I want to create Button and Entry(state=disabled) widgets with a for loop.  The number of widgets to be created will be a runtime argument. What I want is that every time I click the button, the corresponding entry will become enabled(state="normal").  The problem in my code is that any button I click, it only affects the last entry widget. Is there anyway to fix this.? Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class practice:
    def __init__(self,root):
        for w in range(5):
            button=Button(root,text="submit",
                command=lambda:self.enabling(entry1))
            button.grid(row=w,column=0)
            entry1=Entry(root, state="disabled")
            entry1.grid(row=w,column=1)

    def enabling(self,entryy):
        entryy.config(state="normal")

root = Tk()
a = practice(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few issues in your code -

1. You should keep the `buttons` and entries you are creating and save them in an instance variable, most probably it would be good to store them in a list , then `w` would be the index for each button/entry in the list.
2. When you do  `lambda: something(some_param)` - the function value of `some_param()` is not substituted, till when the function is actually called, and at that time, it is working on the latest value for `entry1` , hence the issue. You should not depend on that and rather you should use [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) and send in the index of `Button/Entry` to enable.

Example -

```
from tkinter import *
import functools

class practice:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.button_list = []
        self.entry_list = []
        for w in range(5):
            button = Button(root,text="submit",command=functools.partial(self.enabling, idx=w))
            button.grid(row=w,column=0)
            self.button_list.append(button)
            entry1=Entry(root, state="disabled")
            entry1.grid(row=w,column=1)
            self.entry_list.append(entry1)

    def enabling(self,idx):
            self.entry_list[idx].config(state="normal")


root = Tk()
a = practice(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Wow. that answers my problem! Thank you!

Comment: @Crstn Please do note that the first point I said (in my answer) is important. Otherwise you would end up in mysterious bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever people have problem with a function created with a lambda expression instead of a def statement, I recommend rewriting the code with a def statement until it works right. Here is the simplest fix to your code: it reorders widget creation and binds each entry to a new function as a default arg.

```
from tkinter import *

class practice:
    def __init__(self,root):
        for w in range(5):
            entry=Entry(root, state="disabled")
            button=Button(root,text="submit",
                command=lambda e=entry:self.enabling(e))
            button.grid(row=w,column=0)
            entry.grid(row=w,column=1)

    def enabling(self,entry):
        entry.config(state="normal")

root = Tk()
a = practice(root)
root.mainloop()
```